# Using push notification using Api

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use push notification using Api and I am not getting any error message neither I am getting any response.

I have checked [Apple Push Notification Service with PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891118/apple-push-notification-service-with-php-script/17723596#17723596)

and applied changes in my code accordingly but still not working.

I am not able to get how to get `serverId` that I have to use in

```
$device = 'fbb5a9c71066794d57fee33b4005a89f1bb8941a68660fd6e91f466be1299ab6'; // My iphone deviceToken
$payload['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => 'This is the alert text',
    'badge' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
);

$payload['server'] = array(
    'serverId' => 1,
    'name' => 'keyss.in'
);

$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apnsCert = 'apple_push_notification_production.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

//socket_close($apns); seems to be wrong here ...
fclose($apns);
```

Getting the errors:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not getting any response because you are using the old binary notification format :

```
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

In order to get responses (responses are returned only in case of an error), use the enhanced format :

```
$apnsMessage = pack("C", 1) . pack("N", $apple_identifier) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

You can see sample code [here](http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html).

Comment: Now what is  $apple_identifier and $apple_expiry?

Comment: @Happy `apple_identifier` is a 4 byte identifier that you assign to the message. `apple_expiry` is a 4 byte integer that determines how long the APNS server will try to deliver the notification to the device before giving up. When you receive an error response, it will contain the 4 byte identifier of the notification that caused the error.