# Send data from server to iPhone app

Tags: php, ios, iphone, web-services

I want to add a messaging feature to my iPhone app but I am not sure how to send the data to an iPhone once the sender submits the message.

I am using a PHP webservice to receive the message and add it to a database but from here what would I need to send the message onto the receivers iphone running the same app?

Comment: Have you looked into using APNS? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a native iPhone application, I would recommend using the Apple Push Notification Service and react to those messages within the application.

There are some PHP libraries for using the Apple Push Notification Service:

- [**php-apn**](http://libcapn.org/php-apn/): Needs to be built as an extension. Wraps C code and leverages libcap.
- [**ApnsPHP**](https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP): Pure PHP implementation with Objective-C code examples as well.

Here is a working example from a previous Stack Overflow post on [how to send a simple message using APNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891118/apple-push-notification-service-with-php-script).