# iOS 10 push notification working for gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com but not for gateway.push.apple.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, xcode8

i am working with push notification currently. i have created CSR, Distribution  certificate, mobile provision successfully and added them. My sanbox push is working but production (gateway.push.apple.com) is not working.

See the Dev portal App ID settings: 
[image]

And the keychain is like(Dev and distribution's private key is ok):

[image]

And in code sign identity is- iOS developer and the provision is automatic.

Settings looks like:

[image]

What could be the problem ? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

May be problem is with my pem. From this site: http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/,  i test the push. i'm getting the sanbox but still not getting the production push.

It shows : Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195': (0)

Comment: What build are you using with the production push?  It has to be downloaded from the App Store (or an enterprise app)

Comment: 1. I am using this app to test on-https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12 , it works for sanbox only. 2. I am also trying to test it from my API server to send push. i sent the pem file server. Previously it was working fine. It is not working now.

Comment: try to set automatic mode of provision profiles, and export as ad hoc

Comment: Automatic shows error: **** has conflicting provisioning settings. **** is automatically signed, but code signing identity Automatic has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. @ Vadim Kozak

Answer (score 0):

Some time it might be an issue of .PEM file. Regenerate the .PEM file and upload to your server and test.

Comment: Did it for several time. :(

Answer (score 0):

1.You should enable push notification from capacity in xcode

2. Create a production APNS certificate only
3. Download apn file and  click it
4. Right click on it  & extract this to p12 file and save it into desktop or any where
5. Open your terminal & go to p12 file directory
6. write this command  openssl pkcs12 -in yoursavedfilename.p12 -out yourfilename.pem -nodes -clcerts
7. Now go to server and add this . use sandbox for development & remove sandbox for distribution . Both will work at Production apns .

Comment: For more details see this https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: Done all of this. Could you please explain step 7 again ?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891118/apple-push-notification-service-with-php-script . I said ,use 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195' for development push test & use 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195' for  production test like adhoc or app store

Comment: i don't have the server access currently. Check my updated question.

Comment: Need to enable telnet port 2095 & 2096  of your server . Then i will work.

Comment: So, you are telling this is not pem's problem ? What should i tell to web back end developer ? Please explain more. @ user176196

Comment: tell your web developer , you need to enable telnet port 2095 & 2096 enable for APNS server connection . Actually this will do server administrator . Must need a dedicated host server

Comment: Ok, you should update your answer. I will check tommorrow and let you know. Whatever, Do you ever used https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12 this apps to test APNS ? it's sending me sanbox push message but not the in the production mood.

Comment: Did everything. Problem was in php code. An optional parameter is changed. Thank all of your effort. @ Zahirul Islam

Comment: @JamshedAlam What do you mean by this? Do you have any suggestions for others facing this issue or was it something special to your approach?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in xcode development mode. If you load your app into testflight or app store, gateway.push.apple.com would work well.